# Swap buttons in layout?

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm, performance

Say I have 4 buttons. I want to have button 2 always swap out with another button, randomly. 
So, when the user taps button 2, it should swap with another button (randomly).

Now, `button 2` is at the bottom right corner. So if the user taps button 2 again, it has the option to 
swap with the other three buttons.

I have already tried to make an array of the four values:

```
top_right, top_left, bottom_right, bottom_left
```

And have put them into their own layouts, and the button that is randomly picked swaps with another button. However, this isn't very memory efficient for me.

I would really appreciate it if you were to guide me in solving this!

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

First set tag of your buttons with their numbers

```
btn1.setTag(1);
btn2.setTag(2);
...
```

and put them in an Array:

```
Button[] buttons = {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
```

then define a clickListener for all buttons

```
View.OnClickListener btnListener = View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

         swap((int) v.getTag());
    }
};
```

then assign it to buttons:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
btn2.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
btn3.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
btn4.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
```

and now for swap function:

```
void swap(int butNum){

      Random ran = new Random();
      int randomNum = ran.nextInt(buttons.length - 1) + 1;

      if(randomNum == butNum) randomNum += 1;

      if(randomNum > buttons.length) randomNum = 1;

      Button firstBut = getButtonByTagNum(butNum);
      Button secondBut = getButtonByTagNum(randomNum);

      String s1 = firstBut.getText();
      firstBut.setText(secondButton.getText());
      secondButton.setText(s1);

      firstButton.setTag(randomNumber);
      secondButton.setTag(butNum);
}

Button getButtonByTagNum(int tagNum){

     for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){

          if( ( (int) buttons[i].getTag()) == tagNum - 1){

                 return buttons[i];
          }
     }
}
```

it may need a little polish and debugging. but you get the idea.